# Vue.js: using computed property in method returns undefined error

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

I have a computed property that gets the state from vuex. Inside vuex the state is set using axios to get some data from my api. My issue is that when I try use this computed property inside my methods I get an undefined error. This is because I try use the data before it has been set in the vuex store. So how do I make sure the boardColumnData is set before I try using it in my methods?

errors:

```
Error in mounted hook: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'total' of undefined"
```

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'total' of undefined
```

AppCharts.vue

```
<template>
    <div id="chart_section">
        <div id="charts" v-if="boardColumnData">
            <DoughnutChart :chart-data="datacollection" :options="chartOptions" class="chart"></DoughnutChart>

        <button v-on:click="fillData">Fill Data</button>
    </div>
</template>


<script>
import DoughnutChart from './DoughnutChart';
import { mapGetters } from 'vuex';

export default {
    components: {
        DoughnutChart
    },
    computed: {
        ...mapGetters(['boardColumnData']),
    },
    data() {
        return {
            datacollection: null,
            chartOptions: null
        }
    },
    mounted() {
        this.fillData();
    },
    methods: {
        fillData() {
            this.datacollection = {
                datasets: [{
                    data: [this.boardColumnData[0].total.$numberDecimal, this.boardColumnData[1].total.$numberDecimal, this.boardColumnData[2].total.$numberDecimal, this.boardColumnData[3].total.$numberDecimal],
                    backgroundColor: [
                        '#83dd1a', 
                        '#d5d814',
                        '#fdab2f',
                        '#1ad4dd'
                    ],
                    borderColor: [
                        '#83dd1a', 
                        '#d5d814',
                        '#fdab2f',
                        '#1ad4dd'
                    ],
                }]
            };

            this.chartOptions = {
                responsive: true,
                maintainAspectRatio: false,
            };
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

DoughtnutChart.vue

```
<script>
    import { Doughnut, mixins } from 'vue-chartjs';
    const { reactiveProp } = mixins;

    export default {
        extends: Doughnut,
        mixins: [reactiveProp],
        props: ['chartData', 'options'],
        mounted () {
            this.renderChart(this.chartdata, this.options)
        }
    }
</script>
```

vuex store:

```
import axios from 'axios';

const state = {
    defaultPosts: [],
    boardPosts: [],
    boardColumnData: [],
};

const getters = {
    boardColumnData: state => state.boardColumnData,
};

const actions = {
    getAllBoardPostData: ({commit}) => {
        function getBoardColumns() {
            return axios.get('http://localhost:5000/api/summary-board/columns');
        }

        function getBoardPosts() {
            return axios.get('http://localhost:5000/api/summary-board/posts');
        }

        axios.all([getBoardColumns(), getBoardPosts()])
            .then(axios.spread((columnData, postData) => {
                let rawPosts = postData.data;
                let columns = columnData.data;
                let posts = Array.from({length: columns.length}, () => []);

                rawPosts.forEach((post) => {
                    // If column index matches post column index value
                    if(posts[post.column_index]){
                        posts[post.column_index].push(post);
                    }
                });

                columns.forEach((column, index) => {
                    let columnTotal = 0;

                    posts[index].forEach((post) => {
                        columnTotal += post.annual_value;
                    });

                    column.total.$numberDecimal = columnTotal;
                });

                commit('setBoardColumns', columns);
                commit('setBoardPosts', posts);
                commit('setDefaultPosts', posts);
            }))
            .catch(error => console.log(error));
    }
};

const mutations = {
    setDefaultPosts: (state, payload) => {
        state.defaultPosts = payload;
    },
    setBoardPosts: (state, payload) => {
        state.boardPosts = payload;
    },
    setBoardColumns: (state, payload) => {
        state.boardColumnData = payload;
    }
};

export default {
    state,
    getters,
    actions,
    mutations
};
```

boardColumnData looks like this:

```
[
    {
        "name": "Opportunities",
        "percentage": {
            "$numberDecimal": "0"
        },
        "total": {
            "$numberDecimal": 70269
        }
    },
    {
        "name": "Prospects",
        "percentage": {
            "$numberDecimal": "0.25"
        },
        "total": {
            "$numberDecimal": 0
        }
    },
    {
        "name": "Proposals",
        "percentage": {
            "$numberDecimal": "0.5"
        },
        "total": {
            "$numberDecimal": 5376
        }
    },
    {
        "name": "Presentations",
        "percentage": {
            "$numberDecimal": "0.75"
        },
        "total": {
            "$numberDecimal": 21480
        }
    },
    {
        "name": "Won",
        "percentage": {
            "$numberDecimal": "1"
        },
        "total": {
            "$numberDecimal": 0
        }
    },
    {
        "name": "Lost",
        "percentage": {
            "$numberDecimal": "1"
        },
        "total": {
            "$numberDecimal": 0
        }
    },
    {
        "name": "No Opportunity",
        "percentage": {
            "$numberDecimal": "1"
        },
        "total": {
            "$numberDecimal": 0
        }
    }
]
```

Comment: is `boardColumnData` being fetched from APIs and set inside the store? could you please provide store's relevant code part?

Comment: @CapitanFindus I added my vuex store module.

Comment: where are you calling `getAllBoardPostData` from the store? what about returning a promise from the store, so you can be sure you've already commited `setBoardColumns`

Comment: I call getAllBoardPostData in another component after the AppCharts.vue component on the same page using this.$store.dispatch('getAllBoardPostData'); inside created() . I tried calling it from the AppCharts.vue component but it didn't change anything. I'll have to look into promises for me to try implement them

Comment: @CapitanFindus I have just moved it to the outer component inside the created() function. So it should be set before either of the other two components try use it but I still have the same issue

Comment: that `<div id="charts" v-if="boardColumnData">` will evaluate as `true`, as you should check for `boardColumnData.length`, if it's an array. maybe that solves the issue without modifying the store

Comment: @CapitanFindus still same issue. Adding the errors to my question maybe they help

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212191/discussion-between-capitanfindus-and-reece).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vue should be able to handle the reactivity of updating your components once the data arrives in the store, and since you're passing it into your component correctly, I think you just need to make some small adjustments to make the component more reactive. I'd move the `datacollection` to a computed property, since it's only dependent on the store's `boardColumnData`, and then could you move your `chartOptions` to be defined initially, since it's just static data?

```js
export default {

    data: () => ({
      // datacollection: null,  // remove this
      chartOptions: {
        responsive: true,
        maintainAspectRatio: false,
      },
    },

  //...

  computed: {
    ...mapGetters([
      'boardColumnData'
    ]),
    datacollection() {   // Property added to computed properties
      if (this.boardColumnData.length) {   // - check for boardColumnData before using it
        return {
          datasets: [{
            data: [this.boardColumnData[0].total.$numberDecimal, this.boardColumnData[1].total.$numberDecimal, this.boardColumnData[2].total.$numberDecimal, this.boardColumnData[3].total.$numberDecimal],
            backgroundColor: [
              '#83dd1a', 
              '#d5d814',
              '#fdab2f',
              '#1ad4dd'
            ],
            borderColor: [
              '#83dd1a', 
              '#d5d814',
              '#fdab2f',
              '#1ad4dd'
            ],
          }]
        };

      } else {
        return null;
      }
    }, // end dataCollection()
  },

  //... rest of component...
```

and then in your template, just check for if `datacollection` is has a value. For instance:

```html
<template>
    <div id="chart_section">
        <div id="charts" v-if="datacollection">
            <DoughnutChart
              :chart-data="datacollection"
              :options="chartOptions"
              class="chart"
            />
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set the data before the fillData method is called by using async await on the mounted hook.

In AppCharts.vue, inside your mounted() hook call getAllBoardPostData()

```
`async mounted() {
    await this.$store.dispatch('getAllBoardPostData')
    this.fillData();
},`
```

This will fetch the data from your api and populate your store when the component is loaded, and before the fillData() method is called